# Online check for staff discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Basically I want to make it so that if someone calls command ?server (“There is raid going on!” - for example), people with role “Staff” that also have status “online” would receive dm with message in command
I tried to do it for like an hour but didn’t come up with anything working.

Answer (score 2):

First, we'll get the role itself, then filter out all of the staff and send each a message.  I'm using `asyncio.gather` to send the messages simultaneously, but you can also send them sequentially.

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
from discord import Status
from asyncio import gather

bot = commands.Bot("?")

@bot.command()
async def server(ctx, *, text="There is raid going on!"):
    staff = get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Staff")
    online = (member for member in staff.members if member.status == Status.online)
    messages = (member.send(text) for member in online)  # You could also send the messages sequentially
    await gather(messages)

bot.run("token")
```